# Why is this script not working when the tool is equipped?

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I am trying to make it so when a tool (L1) is equipped, a proximity prompt appears, but my current script doesn't work. Here it is:

```
local Prompt = script.Parent
local Event = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Events"):WaitForChild("HeavyDoor"):WaitForChild("RemoteEvent")

local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

Prompt.Enabled = false

local function IfEquipped()
    Prompt.Enabled = true

    Event:FireServer()

   end

Player.Backpack.L1.Equipped:Connect(IfEquipped())
```

I'd appreciate help! Thanks

Comment: What happens when you try to use this script? Does nothing happen? Does something different from what you wanted happen? Do you see an error message in the log? The more details you can share, the faster users here can help narrow down the problem and suggest solutions.